# Select and Print list of PDF files from a folder

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 issues 
One: i have a list of reports numbers (elements) and the file path (_filePath) now when i use Directory.GetFiles() as per code below filtered based on elements list nothing returned,so may be something wrong with filtering this way, so kindly correct it.
Two: please define the print code in foreach loop

```
// Print the selected files.
  private void PrintReports(Item _itemNo)
    {
        //GetNDEReportDirectory() return directory based on _itemNo
        string _filePath = GetNDEReportDirectory(_itemNo);
        List<string> elements = new List<string>();
        //GetNDEReportsList() return a list of required reports numbers
        elements = GetNDEReportsList(_itemNo);

        //option-2
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(_filePath).Where(f => 
                      elements.Contains(f)).ToList();


        foreach (var file in files)
        {
          //print code

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Directory.GetFiles() returns full file names WITH path, you may want to combine it with System.IO.Path.GetFileName() to get only the file names.

```
List<string> fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(_filePath).Select(d => Path.GetFileName(d)).ToList();
```

Then, depending on what is returned by `GetNDEReportsList(_itemNo);` 
(full file names with path or just the file name?), you can use your existing code.

```
var files = fileNames.Where(f => elements.Contains(f)).ToList();
```

As for the print code, it is not as easy, since you will need third party software to help print, and your requirement of 1 dialog to determine all settings is quite unusual since each document should have its own dialog (they may have different number of pages, etc).

EDIT (you actually need full path names for the print to work using Process):

Basically use the OLD code (from your question, without the edits after seeing the above), and use this instead:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(_filePath).Where(f => elements.Contains(Path.GetFileName(f))).ToList();
```

And then in your foreach, try:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Process p = new Process( );
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( )
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Verb = "print",
        FileName = file
    };
    p.Start( );
}
```

This ensures you use a FULL path of file as FileName, and so it won't say the file is "damaged".

Finally you want to be able to select/change printer name, here is how:

```
System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
pDlg.AllowSomePages = false;
pDlg.ShowHelp = false;
DialogResult result = pDlg.ShowDialog();

// If the result is OK then continue.
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //print your documents here
    foreach (var file in files)
{
    Process p = new Process( );
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( )
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Verb = "print",
        FileName = file,
        Arguments = pDlg.PrinterName
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden     //optional, if you can't hide the adobe window properly with CreateNoWindow
    };
    p.Start( );
}
}
```

Comment: thank you it is working. for the part two of the question i want to print the selected reports to printer, with showing print dialog box only once to set print options. kindly help if possible

Comment: @Hussein I can try to whip something up, shall I add it to this answer, or you're creating a new question for that?

Comment: If possible add it to this answer because it is the second part of the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Keyur PATEL Thanks for the answer, but this code open the pdf file in adobe acrobat and not printing it.Also adobe give error  (the file may be damaged- although the file is ok) and not opening the file.at last no need for Print dialog box but at least i want to set the printer name

Comment: @Hussein According to this MSDN ([ProcessStartInfo.Verb Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx)), specifying the "print" word using `Verb:` should ask Adobe to immediately print the file. However, the path in `FileName = path` has to be a full path, not just the file name (which is what we used).

Comment: @ Keyur PATEL I already concatenated the file path to the file name in for each loop (FileName = _filePath+file + ".pdf" ) so no problem with full path.the second point is how to pass printer name to this code

Comment: @Hussein Check out my edit, it allows you to select printer name once then prints files using that printer.